# Messed up Openoffice and LibreOffice

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, dependencies, libreoffice

I was using Libreoffice, someone suggested me to use openoffice, I installed it but did not liked it, removed it now I can not install libreoffice back. Error is

```
(base) ahmad@ahmad-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx:~$ sudo apt install libreoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:7.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 is to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-draw but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-report-builder-bin but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: fonts-crosextra-caladea but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: fonts-crosextra-carlito but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: fonts-dejavu but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: fonts-linuxlibertine but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: fonts-noto-core but it is not installable
               Recommends: fonts-noto-extra but it is not installable
               Recommends: fonts-noto-ui-core but it is not installable
               Recommends: fonts-sil-gentium-basic but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed or
                           libreoffice-plasma but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-nlpsolver but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-report-builder but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-script-provider-bsh but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-script-provider-js but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-script-provider-python but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-sdbc-mysql but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-wiki-publisher but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-java-common (>= 1:7.0.1~rc2~) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 is to be installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.0.7) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-galaxy : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-tango : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Tried `apt --fix-broken install` but not working.

```
(base) ahmad@ahmad-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-base : Depends: libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:7.0.1~rc2) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-writer : Depends: libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~) but it is not installed
                      Recommends: libreoffice-math but it is not installed
 python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have **-** sign on top of my bar saying that An error occurred, please run package manager. What to do

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 18.04, your packages show you're using 3rd party sources as the packages messages I see don't match Ubuntu repositories for *bionic* - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libreoffice&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all   I'd suggest exploring your sources, eg. a `apt-cache policy` for some of the packages in your messages, as it looks like your sources have been changed creating the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Download packages from TDF site

https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/7.0.1/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_7.0.1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz

https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/7.0.1/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_7.0.1_Linux_x86-64_deb_langpack_en-GB.tar.gz

https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/7.0.1/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_7.0.1_Linux_x86-64_deb_helppack_en-GB.tar.gz

Assuming they are downloaded in: ~/Downloads

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*

sudo apt-get remove --purge openoffice*

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt clean

cd ~/Downloads

for x in *.tar.gz; do tar xfv $x; done

sudo dpkg -i LibreOffice_*/DEBS/*.deb
```

Comment: Future readers: Regex and wildcards (*) don't work with apt in 20.04 and newer. Either use apt-get or use aptitude-style patterns.

Comment: With this solution Libreoffice won't update automatically.

Comment: @To Do: I believed that Ubuntu does not update the versions of the applications that are part of its distribution because it is not a rolling release

Comment: Ubuntu won't upgrade versions, say from 6.4 to 7.0, but it will install minor releases, like 6.4.1 to 6.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some libreoffice PPA that is causing problems. I would:

1. Purge the PPA with `sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-7-0` (install ppa-purge if you do not have it).
2. Try to run `apt --fix-broken install` again.

Then you can either:

1. Try to install libreoffice from the official repositories
2. or add the PPA again with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-7-0` followed by `sudo apt update` and
   `sudo apt install libreoffice`